# codeigniter count_all_results

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

I'm working with the latest `codeIgniter` released, and i'm also working with `jquery` `datatables` from `datatables.net`

I've written this function: https://gist.github.com/4478424  which, as is works fine.  Except when I filter by using the text box typing something in.  The filter itself happens, but my count is completely off.

I tried to add in `$res = $this->db->count_all_results()` before my `get`, and it stops the get from working at all.  What I need to accomplish, `if ($data['sSearch'] != '')` then to utilize the entire query without the `limit` to see how many total rows with the search filter exists.

If you need to see any other code other than whats in my gist, just ask and I will go ahead and post it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`$this->db->count_all_results()` replaces `$this->db->get()` in a database call.

I.E. you can call either `count_all_results()` or `get()`, but not both.

You need to do two seperate active record calls. One to assign the results #, and one to get the actual results.

Something like this for the count:

```
$this->db->select('id');
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where($your_conditions);
$num_results = $this->db->count_all_results();
```

And for the actual query (which you should already have):

```
$this->db->select($your_columns);
$this->db->from('table');
$this->db->where($your_conditions);
$this->db->limit($limit);
$query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: Same in CI 4, countAllResults acts like a Get().

Answer (score 9):

Have you read up on https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#caching ?

I see you are trying to do some pagination where you need the "real" total results and at the same time limiting.

This is my practice in most of my codes I do in CI.

```
    $this->db->start_cache();

    // All your conditions without limit
    $this->db->from();
    $this->db->where(); // and etc...
    $this->db->stop_cache();

    $total_rows = $this->db->count_all_results(); // This will get the real total rows

    // Limit the rows now so to return per page result
    $this->db->limit($per_page, $offset);
    $result = $this->db->get();

    return array(
        'total_rows' => $total_rows,
        'result'     => $result,
    ); // Return this back to the controller.
```

I typed the codes above without testing but it should work something like this. I do this in all of my projects.

Comment: I noticed a recent comment, so I wanted to leave a note of caution: count_all_results will not work correctly if your query has a group by. (This is true for CI 2, I haven't looked at 3). The count_all_results method simply replaces the select w/ a count(*). I'm leaving  my own answer for anyone needing paging w/ more advanced queries

Answer (score 5):

You dont actually have to have the from either, you can include the table name in the count_all_results like so.

```
$this->db->count_all_results('table_name');
```

Answer (score 4):

Count first with no_reset_flag.

```
$this->db->count_all_results('', FALSE);
$rows = $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

---

*system/database/DB_query_builder.php*

```
public function count_all_results($table = '', $reset = TRUE) { ... }
```

Comment: At the time the question was asked, I guess CI 2 was used which does not provide the reset Flag within its params. So for CI 2 I suggest to use Stack Programmer's solution, for CI 3 you can use the Reset flag without beeing forced to cache the query.

Answer (score 1):

The

```
$this->db->count_all_results();
```

actually replaces the:

```
$this->db->get();
```

So you can't actually have both.

If you want to do have both get and to calculate the num rows at the same query you can easily do this:

```
$this->db->from(....);
$this->db->where(....);
$db_results = $this->get();

$results = $db_results->result();
$num_rows = $db_results->num_rows();
```

Comment: He needs to limit the other query so he's not pulling in everything at once, which is why my example includes two distinct queries. Selecting only id (very fast) for the purpose of getting the # of rows and then doing the "slow" query to get the current page's rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 /**
        * @param $column_name   :   Use In Choosing Column name
        * @param $where         :   Use In Condition Statement
        * @param $table_name    :   Name of Database Table
        * Description           :   Count all results   
        */ 
    function count_all_results($column_name = array(),$where=array(), $table_name = array())
    {
        $this->db->select($column_name);
        // If Where is not NULL
        if(!empty($where) && count($where) > 0 )
        {
            $this->db->where($where);
        }
        // Return Count Column
        return $this->db->count_all_results($table_name[0]);//table_name array sub 0
    }
```

Then Simple Call the Method

Like this

```
$this->my_model->count_all_results(['column_name'],['where'],['table name']);
```

Comment: Assuming `$where` is always passed to your `count_all_results()`, then `if(!empty($where) && count($where) > 0 )` is simpler written as `if ($where) {`. This is because `$where` is unconditionally declared and a non-empty array is "truthy".

Answer (score 0):

If your queries contain a group by, using count_all_results fails. I wrote a simple method to work around this. The key to preventing writing your queries twice is to put them all inside a private method that can be called twice. Here is some sample code:

```
class Report extends CI_Model {
    ...
    public function get($page=0){
        $this->_complex_query();
        $this->db->limit($this->results_per_page, $page*$this->results_per_page);
        $sales = $this->db->get()->result(); //no table needed in get()

        $this->_complex_query();
        $num_results = $this->_count_results();

        $num_pages = ceil($num_results/$this->results_per_page);

        //return data to your controller
    }

    private function _complex_query(){
        $this->db->where('a', $value);
        $this->db->join('(subquery) as s', 's.id = table.s_id');
        $this->db->group_by('table.column_a');

        $this->db->from('table'); //crucial - we specify all tables here
    }

    private function _count_results(){
        $query = $this->db->get_compiled_select();
        $count_query = "SELECT count(*) as num_rows FROM (".$query.") count_wrap";
        $r = $this->db->query($count_query)->row();
        return $r->num_rows;
    }
}
```